# Animation cannot resolve?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, transition

Trying to do a simple shared element animation, and it works fine when just one element is shared. I am trying to experiment by sharing two elements, and that's the problem:

```
      ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Main2Activity.this, Pair.create((View) back, "agreedName1"), Pair.create((View) animate, "agreedName2"));
```

AND

```
 Pair<View, String> h = Pair.create((View) back, "agreedName1");
            Pair<View, String> k = Pair.create((View) animate, "agreedName1");
            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Main2Activity.this, h, k);
```

Both don't work, because apparently:

> Error:(35, 54) error: no suitable method found for
>   makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Main2Activity,android.support.v4.util.Pair,android.support.v4.util.Pair)
>   method
>   ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity,View,String) is
>   not applicable (argument mismatch;
>   android.support.v4.util.Pair cannot be converted to
>   View) method
>   ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity,android.util.Pair...)
>   is not applicable (varargs mismatch;
>   android.support.v4.util.Pair cannot be converted to
>   android.util.Pair)

Even though `back` and `animate` are both buttons (I even tried typecasting them to views).

---

Again, this works fine with just one view animation like so:

```
 ActivityOptionsCompat options1 = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, animate, "transition1"); //CANT HAVE TWO TRANSITIONS WITHOUT PAIR HOWEVER
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

### How can I successfully execute shared animation with two elements?

The way I am doing it (in my first two examples) is how it is said to be done in the developer docs on [shared element transition.](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#CurvedMotionhttp://)

**The docs clearly state:**

> To make a scene transition animation between two activities that have
>   more than one shared element, define the shared elements in both
>   layouts with the android:transitionName attribute (or use the
>   View.setTransitionName() method in both activities), and create an
>   ActivityOptions object as follows:

```
> ActivityOptions options =
> ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
>         Pair.create(view1, "agreedName1"),
>         Pair.create(view2, "agreedName2"));
```

**Which I am doing. If I am doing everything right, how come I am getting this error?**

Answer (score 1):

replace at the top of your class:

`import android.support.v4.util.Pair`

by

`import android.util.Pair`

and it should work. You're just using the wrong pair.

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy; You just need a cast of that. Like below example:

```
    ActivityOptions opt = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                            this,
                            (Pair<View, String>) Pair.create(view1, "agreedName1"),
                            (Pair<View, String>) Pair.create(view2, "agreedName2"));
```

I hope this can help to you. :)